# How do you use a fingerprint Scanner on 13.10

Tags: 13.10, thinkpad

I have a ThinkPad T410s and I can't use the fingerprint scanner installed? Any Suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few questions and responses to Fingerprint scanners on Ask Ubuntu.

Unfortunately these scanners appear to be quite proprietary and open-source support very limited.

There appears to only be the one Linux fingerprint scanner project.  I could not get this working on my laptop either.

Anyway give this a go http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-get-your-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu

and best of luck!!

Comment: This page seems to imply that the Fingerprint GUI should work with the Thinkpad T410s.

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_enable_the_integrated_fingerprint_reader

Comment: As this page suggests (https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint) run lsusb to get the manufacturer id of your fingerprint scanner then compare it to the list of supported scanners on the page.